# Want a regular expression to validate a number format

Tags: regex

I have a specific number format as: 1-2345678908765 where first digit is separated by '-' and thirteen number following it. I tried using:

```
[]?[0-9]\-^[0-9]{1,13}$
```

but didn't work.

Thanks in Advance

Sanjay Suman

Comment: Try: `^[0-9]-[0-9]{13}$`

Comment: What's the `^` for in there? That indicates start of string

Comment: @MarcB but in the middle of the string it indicates negation, still not sure why he uses it...

Comment: @alfasin: no, it's only a negation if it's at the start of a character class. `[^abc]` v.s. `^[abc]` are two totally different things.

Answer (score 3):

It seems your regular expression syntax is malformed, the first issue is that `[]?[0-9]` if using ([**PCRE**](http://pcre.org/)) forms a character class which matches any one character from the set of characters.

Otherwise, `[]?` does a zero-width match because you have an empty optional class.

You also have the beginning of string `^` anchor placed after the hyphen in which the following numbers do not assert at that given position in the string.

You can use the following regex instead:

```
^[0-9]-[0-9]{13}$
```

**Explanation**:

```
^            # the beginning of the string
 [0-9]       #   any character of: '0' to '9'
 -           #   '-'
 [0-9]{13}   #   any character of: '0' to '9' (13 times)
$            # before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

**[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qS0dO0/1)**

Answer (score 0):

```
"/^[0-9][-][0-9]{13}$/"
```

It will match a single number, followed by 1 hypen, followed by 13 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try `/^[0-9][\-][0-9]{13}$/gm`

You can test out regular expressions at [regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it finally.

[]?[0-9]-[0-9]{13}

Answer (score 0):

Working on this please try for grouping and may be this is usefully for your needs in future e.g. find and replace. If you want to find all lines beginning with "1":

(^[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3gRU.png){1})-([0-9]{13})

To exchange the first and second value you pnly need a "\2-\1" in the "Replace" textbox of NotePad++ for example.

[image]

BTW - please check https://www.regex101.com/ for your needs.